# How to set url for images in react-static build in scss file

Tags: reactjs, sass, react-static

I'm migrating my React site to react-static. I have a css in scss files and I use `react-static-plugin-sass` in my project. How do I set correctly an URL for images in my scss files?

I tried this:

```
.my-page {
  color: rgb(70, 81, 116);
  &_header {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-image: url(/assets/images/bg-illustration.jpg);
  }
}
```

but when I run the site it gives me the following error:

> Cannot GET /assets/images/bg-illustration.jpg

My assets are located in src folder:

```
-src
--assets
---images
----bg-illustration.jpg
```

It seems that all images that are mentioned in scss files are just not copied to the result folder with assets.

I'd appreciate any info about how I can fix it in react-static build.

Comment: Using relative paths might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67038552/how-to-set-url-for-images-in-react-static-build-in-scss-file/67044463#comment118497062_67038552) by Eusbolh, you need to use **relative** path for the URL. E.g:

```css
background-image: url(../../assets/images/test.png);
```

Note that when we start a path with `/`, e.g. `/foo/bar.png`, it tries to read the image from `public` directory.

Comment: thanks for your input, but unfortunately it doesn't work, if I remove "/" it gives an error "ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve /path to image/". The only one way how it can be compiled without error with path with "/" but in this case there is no image

Comment: here is the repo: https://github.com/annmirosh/react-static-test